# Make row of table clickable with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, href, semantic-ui

Now there is clickable only a table cell containing an icon, like here at the end:

```
<Table.Body>
  {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <Table.Row key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}>
      {emptyFirstHeader && (
        <Table.Cell>
          <Image
            src={row.cells[0]}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
      )}
      {
        (emptyFirstHeader ? row.cells.shift() : row,
        row.cells.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
          if (cell === undefined) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <Table.Cell key={idList}>
              {cell}
            </Table.Cell>
          );
        }))
      }

      <Table.Cell>
        <Link //here is the link done - inside a table cell
            to={
              entityName &&
              `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`
            }>
            <Icon name="ellipsis horizontal" />
          </Link>
      </Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

My goal is to make the whole row clickable (and redirect to that new link). So I've tried to make the row clickable:

```
<Table.Body>
  {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <Table.Row key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}>
      {emptyFirstHeader && (
        <Table.Cell>
          <Image
            src={row.cells[0]}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
      )}
      {
        (emptyFirstHeader ? row.cells.shift() : row,
        row.cells.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
          if (cell === undefined) {
            return null;
          }
          return (
            <Table.Cell key={idList}>
              {cell}
            </Table.Cell>
          );
        }))
      }

      <Table.Cell>       
        <Icon name="ellipsis horizontal" />
      </Table.Cell>
         // moved it outside the Tabel.Cell and now it is inside Table.Row
         <Link to={entityName && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`}>
         </Link>
    </Table.Row>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

But unfortunately it's not working. Is there a way to change it and make the whole row clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<Table.Row>` element inside the `<Link>` element. Doing so will "wrap a `<Link>` behavior around the `<Table.Row>`".

I believe this code will solve your problem:

```
<Table.Body>
  {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <Link to={entityName && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`}>    
      <Table.Row key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}>
        {emptyFirstHeader && (
            <Table.Cell>
                <Image src={row.cells[0]} />
            </Table.Cell>
        )}
        {
          (emptyFirstHeader ? row.cells.shift() : row, row.cells.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
            if (cell === undefined) {
              return null;
            }
            return (
              <Table.Cell key={idList}>
                {cell}
              </Table.Cell>
            );
          }))
        }
        <Table.Cell>       
          <Icon name="ellipsis horizontal" />
        </Table.Cell>         
      </Table.Row>
    </Link>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

Comment: it seems to make it clickable but it destroys the format of the table, I don't know why. look how it looked before https://i.imgur.com/sN7zEpM.png and how it looks after the change https://i.imgur.com/z9zsgA6.png

Comment: @SamuraiJack Any style you might have added to the `<Link>` element could be the source of the problem. Providing more of the code you've written (a GitHub repository, for example) would make it easier for me (and others) to help.

Comment: There is no styling added. It's complicated to make a running example here but I can post the file code here: https://pastebin.com/ThWB4mwr

Comment: the only difference I see in inspect is that it adds a section, **inherited from a** https://i.imgur.com/OaZyhsm.png if there is a way to disable it

Comment: @SamuraiJack Wrap what's **inside** your `<Table.Row>` element with a `<Link>`, instead of the `<Table.Row>` itself. I believe it may solve the problem.